# clean code inside of mutate = case_when in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, case-when

im wondering if it is possible to shorten up the code in this case_when() statement. Another important goal is to make the length  inside the case_when() statement (amount of times lag(..., n=xy) below each other) variable.
The purpose of this function is to find the closest leading object with the same id and assign a value to it. (but its more about not writing 10 times n=1,2,3,4,5...)

Here is my code:

```
  find.after <- function(data, expr) {
    data %>% mutate(
      "a.{{expr}}" := case_when(
        lead(id,1) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},1),
        lead(id,2) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},2),
        lead(id,3) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},3),
        lead(id,4) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},4),
        lead(id,5) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},5),
        lead(id,6) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},6),
        lead(id,7) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},7),
        lead(id,8) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},8),
        lead(id,9) == id ~ lead({{ expr }},9)
      )
    )
  }

tibble(id = rep(1:5,2), b = rep(c("a","b"),5)) %>%
  find.after(data = ., expr = b)
```

Any tipps would be super cool! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hey, ```dput(head(tibble(id = rep(1:5,2), b = rep(c("a","b"),5)))``` would result in 
```structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), b = c("a", "b", 
"a", "b", "a", "b"), a.b = c("b", "a", "b", "a", "b", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What's the output you're trying to get?

Comment: I try to generate a new column, that contains "closest" value of b where a condition is met. But it's more about, never write the same code more that 3 times below each other. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `case_when` here, you just need a `group_by`

```
find.after <- function(data, expr) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate("a.{{expr}}" = lead({{expr}}))
}
```

This way you are always only looking within the same `id` for the next value

Comment: I was not thinking it would be that easy to solve problems like these! I guess in this case, there is just no usecase for creating this weird conditions like in the original post via apply or so. (which i was trying to find)